# How to Get number of hits to the Web API method

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, global-asax

I have an application there, I am using Web API calls for all my operations.

Now I have a requirement that, I need to track down our API calls, means how many times my API got called and which method called how many times. Every information I need to insert into the database for future response too.

Anyone has any idea how to achieve?  Please share.

**What I am thinking:**

In global.asax under application_beginrequest I will check the url and will try to find the API method name.

Then the method name can be pushed to the DB by doing an asynchronous call.

**Note:**
Does it will slow down API performance?,

Comment: I'm guessing the best would be writing a "trackdown" method, class, whatever.. and use it inside each api action

Comment: I have tried the below approach because the api is already there modifying api code i don't think it's a good idea because we have many methods so what I did I have created a global action filter and in those action filters I have written some code to track API method calls. Thank you  for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ActionFilter. You do not want to litter your code with logging.

```
public class MyLoggingFilter: ActionFilterAttribute 
{


    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        Log...
       //actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
        //actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        Log...
    }
}
```

Then you should register the action filter for all controllers in your WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
        // Web API configuration and services

        config.Filters.Add(new MyLoggingFilter());

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

Then consider using a Logging framework like Log4Net or NLog - these frameworks will have appenders to log to any storage type (SQL, to file, whatever). These frameworks will log asynchronously so will not slow down the execution of your requests.